# How do I check if the user completed the share action using react native share

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-share

I am having an issue using react native share. When a user clicks on social sharing, immediately the social app(facebook, instagram or twitter) is opened, I get a promise informing me that the file or data has been shared. However, at this point when a user cancels the share action I dont get any information on that.

So my question is - Is there a way to know when a user cancel the share action after leaving my app and in the social apps(facebook, instagram or twitter). ie. how to know if the share action has actually been completed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems it is not possible with the current implementation. Please go through this thread
https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/1112